# Why my installed python module is not being imported in script?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I am trying to learn python for GUI, I have worked on python for some time now.
I have installed pyforms module but when I try to import that module in my script it gives error saying no such module is available? Has any one faced this problem?
I have attached image to clarify what exactly is the problem.
Thanks in advance for any help on this.
Following is my output on my terminal.

```
C:\Dhaval\Learning\office>pip show pyforms
Name: PyForms
Version: 4.0.3
Summary: Pyforms is a Python framework to develop GUI applications based on pyqt
Home-page: https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pyforms
Author: Ricardo Ribeiro
Author-email: ricardojvr@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\dhava\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages
Requires: pyforms-terminal, pyforms-web, pyforms-gui
Required-by:

C:\Dhaval\Learning\office>python GUIExample.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GUIExample.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyforms
ImportError: No module named pyforms

C:\Dhaval\Learning\office>pip install pyforms
Requirement already satisfied: pyforms in c:\users\dhava\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (4.0.3)
```

Below is my Code in file GUIExample.py

```
import pyforms
from pyforms.basewidget import BaseWidget
from pyforms.controls   import ControlFile
from pyforms.controls   import ControlText
from pyforms.controls   import ControlSlider
from pyforms.controls   import ControlPlayer
from pyforms.controls   import ControlButton


print ("Hello World")
```

P.S - If I execute same script with pycharm then it works fine.

[image]
Please refer the image which shows clearly what the problem is.

Comment: Did you try "python3 GUIExample.py" ?

Comment: Please refer to the guidelines at  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for creating a minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command first. Maybe you have not installed the modules since they are not installed in default.

> pip install pyforms

Comment: Thanks for your answer albert, but I have already tried that multiple times.

Comment: This is what the out put is,
C:\Dhaval\Learning\office>pip install pyforms
Requirement already satisfied: pyforms in c:\users\dhava\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (4.0.3)

Comment: What feedback do you get after running that command?